# Numerical analysis the use of Fast Fourier Transform

Tags: numerical-methods

If I am going to use the pseudo-spectral method to solve
$$
u_t = -u_{xxx} - 6uu_x,
$$
how do I set up the RHS?

Would it be

1. $-\left[\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[(ik)^3\mathcal{F}(u(x))\right] + u\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[(ik)\mathcal{F}(u(x))\right]\right]$ or
2. $-\left[\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[(ik)^3\mathcal{F}(u(x)) + u(ik)\mathcal{F}(u(x))\right]\right]$ or
3. Is there another way it is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $2uu_x = \partial_x(u^2)$. Doing the Fourier transform on the equation (x-k) gives

$$(\mathcal{F}u)_t = ik^3\mathcal{F}u - 3ik\mathcal{F}(u^2).$$

Taking the inverse Fourier transform gives

$$u_t = i\,\mathcal{F}^{-1}(k^3\mathcal{F}u - 3k\mathcal{F}(u^2)).$$

Making use of the convolution theorem, we can simplify this a little bit. We know that $\mathcal{F}(f\ast g) = \mathcal{F}f\cdot\mathcal{F}g$ (for suitable functions $f$ and $g$). Rewriting this, we have

$$\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}^{-1}f\ast\mathcal{F}^{-1}g) = f\cdot g.$$

How does this help us? Well note that we have $\mathcal{F}(u^2)$. By the convolution theorem, this is just

$$\mathcal{F}(u^2) = \mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}^{-1}u\ast\mathcal{F}^{-1}u)) = \mathcal{F}^2(\mathcal{F}^{-1}u\ast\mathcal{F}^{-1}u).$$

There's a nice property of the Fourier transform that says that $\mathcal{F}^2 u = u(-x),$ so we have

$$\mathcal{F}(u^2)(k) = (\mathcal{F}^{-1}u\ast\mathcal{F}^{-1}u)(-k).$$

You could then substitute this in above if you felt like it. Convolution is very well-behaved as it is a smoothing property so numerically, this might be the way to go.

Comment: I am writing more up. One second.

Comment: @dustin I'm not sure how that's the case haha. I can't figure out why it would be like that.

Comment: @dustin Have you checked your results against a finite difference method? I feel like something strange is going on.

Comment: @dustin Yeah please do.